# How to make Div over a body

Tags: javascript, html, css, popup

I'm going to develop an addon for Firefox, but I have a problem with the design. To explain the situation in the following picture you see a popup which has a darkgrey box in it. This box I animated from top to bottom, so it slow move in the popup. This is a div, and I want that the div is over the white body. So the div is animated in and everything behind is no more visible, but the div has the same width and same height as the body. You can still see the body right and left and on top and at the bottom, but why? How can I do it that the div is over the body design?

The picture: http://prntscr.com/puo44r

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
          <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<style>
          body {
                    background-color: white;
                    width: 385px;
                    height: 520px;
                    text-align: center;
          }

          .kw_popup {
                    display: none;
                    background-color: #333;
                    width: 385px;
                    height: 520px;
                    z-index: -1;
          }
</style>
<body>
          <div class="kw_popup" id="kw_dark">
          </div>
</body>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>$(document).ready(function () {
                    $("#kw_dark").slideDown("slow");
          });</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `position: fixed` to div.

When element has `position: fixed` it is removed from flow of the page and it will be above every element of page.

Hope this helps.. Comment down if it doesn't :)